# What is the effect of cold temperatures on aircraft gyroscopic instruments?

Tags: aircraft-systems, cold-weather

When it comes to cold temperatures, I know some effects on engine, for example it causes higher viscosity of oil and so higher oil pressure when engine is just started but still cold.

But what is the effect of cold temperatures on Gyroscopic instruments?

Comment: I think this would be a huge answer with lots of possibilities and variances, it can't be answered with "X will happen to all" and this question can be more thoroughly researched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gyro instruments will have tiny caged ball and roller bearings for moving components. They will normally contain light oil or possibly a low viscosity grease.

Low temps will have some effect, perhaps making gyros spin up a bit slower until the bearings warm up.  But the effect may be too minor to notice. I've never been able to tell when flying in winter.